# Property set to false, but target still executed

Tags: ant

Here's a simple Ant build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Project" default="build" basedir=".">
    <property name="compressAssets" value="false"/>

    <target name="build" depends="compress-assets"/>
    <target name="compress-assets" if="compressAssets">
        <echo message="executed"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

`compressAssets` is set to `false`, so how come the `compress-assets` target is executed every time? Note the `if` property on the target.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if` does not check for the value of the property, it checks if the property has been set.

---

From the [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/):

```
<target name="build-module-A" if="module-A-present"/>
```

> [...] if the `module-A-present` property is set (to any value, e.g. ***false***), the target will be run.

Comment: So Ant is using a different meaning for "if" than the rest of the entire programming world.

Answer (score 5):

In Ant 1.8, `if` now does check that the value is true (`unless` checks for false), so you can do:

```
<target name="blah" if="${do-blah}">
    .
    .
    .
</target>
```